# NavigationBar и ActionBar XML

Tags: java, android, xml, android-navigation-drawer

ActionBar закрывает часть информации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под ним есть кнопка, которую не видно.

**main**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/bar_drawer"/>
```

**app_bar**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.raymaletdin.logview.view.StatusLog">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/activity_status_log"/>
```

**status_log(основной экран)**  Обрати внимание fitsSystemWindows=true

```
<HorizontalScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorMyBackground"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 ///кнопки />
```

**styles**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>-->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorOrangeTwo</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorOrangeThree</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorMyBackground</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**OnCreate**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_status_log_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: Вы забыли добавить `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` для `ScrollView`

Comment: Благодарю! Вы решили мою проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли добавить

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

для ScrollView